# Switch between resources DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on MFC solution that consists of many projects. One of my projects "App.exe" depends on other project output dll "SC.dll".

I added reference to the other project via Add Reference option under the App project.

I want to "based on an option" switch between languages by using resources dll. 
I've another resources project that produces Arabic resources "SC_AR.dll".

I tried to use LoadLibrary based on the option ,but it failed.

1. Is the "Add Reference" approach is wrong?
2. If not, how I could switch between the Dlls?
3. If yes, what is the right approach to follow?

Comment: does Microsoft has [How to Create Localized Resource DLLs for MFC Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198846) ?

Comment: Yes, it has. But, it's not applicable on my scenario.
As 
>>1- I am using a helper DLL from the application which I added reference as mentioned.
>>2- I want to localize the helper Dll itself. And I don't use the LoadLibrary.
>>3- I created localized project and I want to switch between them according to the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MFC doesn't support Arabic, I made an English dialog and Arabic one inside the dll. And according to the Language property I send the resource ID to the Constructor of Dialog.
And for any String I use LoadString

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to reference a [resource satellite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0.aspx). MFC searches satellite DLLs using the user's Windows UI language and your application's file name. To switch to another satellite, call LoadLibrary() and then call AfxSetResourceHandle().

Of course, this is assuming you are loading all resources via MFC (e.g. use CString::LoadString instead of LoadResource ).  You have to use your own satellite DLL handle explicitly if you call API directly.

PS [the less said about SetThreadLocale](http://www.siao2.com/2005/08/22/454360.aspx) the better.

Comment: This is correct ,but won't work in nested resources loading. As after I load the main app resources I need to set another Dll resource which doesn't load and leads to unloading the main exe resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MFC then the resource dll is loaded in the boilerplate that's generated in the main file. (can't rememebr it offhand) but search for LoadResource(). You'll have to call LoadLibrary to get the hmodule to pass into this.

Be aware that if you're displaying resources from several dlls, you will have to be careful about dialogs in a different resource dll. If youre simply swapping dlls, you won't have a problem.

Comment: I called the LoadLibrary givin it the Dll name ,but NULL is returned.

Please notice that I don't use LoadLibrary for the English DLL, I just added reference to it.<br\>